# An inequality for the Poisson integral of an $L^p$ function

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

In Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, in Theorem 11.16 page 239-240 he says that if $f\in L^p(T)$     (T is the unit circle) and if $u=P[f]$, where $P[f]$ is the Poisson integral of $f$, then $||u_r||_p\le||f||_p ,0\le r\le1 (u_r(e^{\theta i})=u(re^{\theta i}))$.

In the proof he says that

$|u_r(e^{i\theta})|^p\le1/2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|^pP_r(\theta-t)dt $

and that this inequality can be deduced from Holder. Can someone explain how does this follow from Holder?

Thanks.

Comment: It's actually easier to go back to Jensen, which gives it immediately.

Comment: @zhw i am probably doing something wrong but doesnt Jensen give $|u_r(e^{i\theta})|^p\le1/2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|^pP_r(\theta-t)^pdt $

Comment: It does gives that, but treat $(1/2\pi)P_r\,dt$ as a measure of mass $1$ and you'll have what you want.

Comment: @zhw Ohh i see..Thanks!